# Laravel Return Grouped Many To Many Relations

Tags: laravel

How do you return a collection of a grouped dataset in a ManytoMany relationship with this scenario?

Here is a sample of what dataset I want to return

[image]

So let's take the favorites as the genres and the highlighted date is the `genres name`, it's also a collection as well. I want to group it based on the `genres name` in that collection.

My model:

Video

````
```
public function genres() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Genre::class);
}
```
````

Genre

````
```
public function videos() {
    return $this->belongsToMany(Video::class);
}
```
````

I tried the following already but can't seem to get it.

````
```
$videos = Video::with('genres')->all();
$collection = $videos->groupBy('genres.name');
```
````

I want to group the dataset by the genres name knowing the genre's relationship is also a collection of genres.

Comment: hey, where is $collection coming from?

Comment: Oh sorry, I meant to assign the returned dataset into the collection variable.

Comment: You probably want to eager load the genres with `Video::with('genres')->all();` as well

Comment: Yeah! I have the dataset eager loaded already, I want to group the returned dataset into this format:


"Blues": [
    { "name": "Blues" },
    { "name": "Blues" },
],
"Hip Hop": [
    { "name": "Blues" }
]

Comment: Edit your question and add the desired result. You might want to turn the query around into something like this: `$genres = Genre::with('videos')->get()`

Comment: Not all of the genres have videos in them when I query for all videos, they result set tells the genres that have videos in them. Which is why I want to group that result set by the genres. I don't know if you get my point exactly.

Comment: You can add a [`has(..)`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence) to the query: `$genres = Genre::has('videos')->with('videos')->get()`

Comment: This is much more complicated than it seems on first look, because video's genres are a collection (it's also the reason why simple `groupBy('genres.name')` doesn't work - as `genres` is not an object). I'm afraid you'll need to write some complicated logic for grouping yourself using the `->groupBy(function ($item) {..})`  callback if you're set on doing this with collections

Answer (score 3):

Try something like:

```php
Video::with('genres')->get()->groupBy('genres.*.name');
```

**Or:**

```php
$videos = Video::with('genres')->all();
$collection = $videos->groupBy('genres.*.name');
```

> **Note** that above is code you posted, just after replacing "`genres.name`" with "`genres.*.name`".
>
> Just noticed the post is old, this at least works on latest Laravel.

Answer (score -1):

Collections and query builders share many similar functions such as where() groupBy() and so on.  It's nice syntax sugar, but it really does obscure the underlying tech.

1. If you call $model->videos... like a property, that's a collection (query has executed).
2. If you call $model->videos()... like a method, that's a query builder.

So if you want to get the job done in sql, you can do something like...

```
$video_query_builder = Video::with('genere');
$video_query_builder->groupBy('genere_id');
$result = $video_query_builder->get();
```

You can chain it all together nice and neatly as was suggested in the comments... like this:

```
$result = Video::with('genere')
               ->groupBy('genere_id')
               ->get();
```

Comment: This would do the same: `$result = Video::with('genre')->groupBy('genre_id')->get()`. Not sure that it would work, just wanted to mention there's no reason for 3 lines.

Comment: @devk is totally right.  You can chain it all together.  My long-windedness was just for clarity.

Comment: This wouldn't work because there's no genre_id on the videos table, it's a many to many relationship using a pivot table. A video can have multiple genres or a single one.

Comment: Or, maybe you want to get all generes with videos?  Just go at it from the other direction?

Comment: Using a collection would be preferable.

Comment: If you use a collection - then it may be simplest to add a genre slug maker to your video model.  Then you can group by that.  add something like this to the Video.php model class.  public function getGenreSlugAttribute(){ return implode('-', $this->generes->pluck('name')->flatten()->toArray()); }

Then you can Videos::with('genere')->get()->groupBy('genre_slug');

Comment: Basically, make a model property on the fly that you can group by.

Comment: Probably want to order the generes by name...  So that would better be $this->generes()->orderBy('name')->get->pluck...  for slug consistancy

Comment: @TarekAdam using the genre_slug got me exactly the collection dataset I wanted. Thanks a billion man.

Comment: Awesome!  Glad to hear it!  I'll update the post for the next person.

Comment: I wasn't able to sort or order the result based on the genres name. Any last tip on that?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169550/discussion-between-tarek-adam-and-samtoya).